# Javascript regex match doesn't run correctly

Tags: javascript, regex

okay I give up. Here's my code:

```
var re = /href="(http.*\.jpg)"/g;
var mp3s = body.match(re);
```

it finds pictures, but it returns href="http://www.picture.com/smthg.jpg"

instead of returning http://www.picture.com/smthg.jpg

any idea why?

Comment: Because you're including the `href` attribute in the match

Comment: When you have access to the DOM, why bother using something so primitive as regular expressions? It seems pretty naive.

Comment: because it is faster than importing a dom parser library. This really doesn't answer my question. The regex seems fine to me I don't see where is the problem... I capture the group excluding the href

Comment: If you want to make sure that there is a "href=" before your link but not catch it, look up "lookbehind regular expression" in Google, it will do just that.

Comment: lookbehind is not supported in javascript

Comment: @David天宇Wong, are you running this code in Node? Writing code faster is not a virtue when it's low quality.

Comment: yes I do write this code in node. What I meant by faster: it's lighter and faster to parse it with a regex than with a dom parser. If I'll have more time I'll do some tests but it seems fairly obvious to me.

Answer (score 2):

The result from `match()` is actually an object.

I think you need to access the first element on that object.

For example:

```
body.match(re)[1]
```

This is where the actual result is kept.

Shameless self-promotion:
 I've written a small guide for me, I can never remember how to use these either. It's here: http://queirozf.com/reminders/javascript-regular-expressions-usage-reminder

Comment: It's not really a self-promotion if you didn't promote yourself - where's your guide at? Can we see it? :)

Comment: @Zlatko =) ok then there you go.

Comment: I console.log it and I only get one result, the one with the entire thing and not just the capture group.

Comment: Now it's a self-promotion :) Though not a shameless one, I think these short reminders are excellent and they can also help out others like this.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var re = /(http.*\.jpg)/g;
var mp3s = body.match(re);
```

since you don't need the href.

Comment: yeah but I want to be sure that it is in a link, not like that.

Answer (score 0):

You want to match the regular expression, but then return just the portion in brackets.

To do this, call the regular expressions `exec` method. For example:

```
var body = 'stuff stuff morestuff href="http://www.picture.com/smthg.jpg" and some more stuff';
var re = /href="(http.*\.jpg)"/g;
var regexResults = re.exec(body);
var mp3s = regexResults[1];
alert(mp3s);
```

Having given you this answer, I must implore you to find a different way to solve this problem. You cannot parse HTML using regular expressions. No matter how sophisticated your regular expression gets, there will be a legal HTML example which will break it.

Comment: do you have a quicker solution when I just need to get .jpg ? A entire dom parser seems too heavy to me.